# selenium + python - finding an element and moving to a clickable link

Tags: python, selenium

I have been learning python and working with selenium for a month or so and I am stuck on one last thing I need for my script.

The script selects an element and clicks on it. I can do this directly but I have realised that the identifier for the element keeps changing so I would like to select it by text.

This is the html snippet:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none;" onclick="getClassDetails('265090', '614617')" class="spinstudio">    <div>
    <div class="triangle"></div>
        <p style="padding:10px 25px 0 25px;font-size:13px">RPM 80</p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:left;float:left;padding:0;margin:0;">
        600 cals
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:12px;text-align:right;float:right;padding:0;margin:0;">
        30 mins
        </p>
    </div>      
</a>
```

The clickable element is the onclick of course. I have managed to get this working by using the number:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'\"getClassDetails('265090')\"')]")
```

and by xpath:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[12]/div[3]/div[8]/a').click()
```

but as I said both of those keep changing and I need to run this periodically. So I thought try to select by tag name and then move to the clickable link and click it. And this is where I would like some help please. I have started with this

```
button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("//p[contains('RPM 80')]")
```

and tried some ActionChains options but I am a bit lost.

Also, I think I might have a scenario where there are two elements with the same tag ("RPM 80" for example) on the page. Is there a way to select one of them (I need both selected but separately in different scripts).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes this div tag distinct from other div tags on the page?

Comment: Also to use contains on the tag text use text()='RPM 80'.

Comment: The only difference is the names (RPM 80, 600 cals, 30 mins). The rest is identical

Comment: so:
```
button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("//p[contains(text()='RPM 80')]")
```
?

Answer (score 0):

For Selection, you can use -

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[contains(text(),"30 mins")]/preceding-sibling::p[contains(text(),"600 cals")]/parent::div/parent::a[@onclick]')
```

Don't forget these imports -

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

For Selecting one of the element with 'RPM 80' text -

```
# This will select the first `p` element with "RPM 80" text
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//p[contains('RPM 80')])[1]")
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Looks like it did not work

button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("(//p[contains('RPM 80')])[1]")

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: this one looks like it is working

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[contains(text(),"600 cals")]/preceding-sibling::p[contains(text(),"The Les Mills Sprint 16")]/parent::div/parent::a[@onclick]').click()


Thank you. 
So if there happen to be 2 elements that fit that criteria on the page is there a way to select the one I want?

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer - it has to be  `find_element_by_xpath` not `tag name`. Please check now and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To click the a tag try this XPath:
`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[text() = "RPM 80"]/parent::div/parent::a').click()`

Comment: One thing I tried was an earlier suggestion on top of this one. SO

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[text() = "RPM 80"][1]/parent::div/parent::a').click()

successfully locates the first instance, but 

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//p[text() = "RPM 80"][2]/parent::div/parent::a').click()

does not find the second.